# How await parallel spark reads?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Consider the code:

```
val reads = Future.traverse(mycollection)(p => Future {
  session.read
    .json(p)
    .write
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .parquet(destinationTableLocation)
}(ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool( session.sparkContext.defaultParallelism ))))

Await.ready(reads, Duration.Inf)
```

And here spark driver stops. Isthere a way to await for all futures?

P.S. do not sugect passing `mycollection` to `json` function- this is another story :)

Comment: The code looks legit. Note that `Await.ready` will not throw an exception if the future is failed, could it be your case?

Comment: I think no, because I saw (for some seconds) tasks started in spark UI.